# docker desktop in Windows 10 Enterprise showing errors

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-desktop

I am having an error whenever I start docker desktop and don't know how to deal with it.

I have tried reinstalling but the same thing happens.

```
Unable to create: The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Generic failure 
at New-Switch, <No file>: line 121
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 411
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.Send(String action, Object[] parameters) in C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeClient.cs:line 36
   at Docker.Actions.DoStart(SynchronizationContext syncCtx, Boolean showWelcomeWindow, Boolean executeAfterStartCleanup) in C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Windows\Actions.cs:line 92
   at Docker.Actions.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<Start>b__0() in C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Windows\Actions.cs:line 74
   at Docker.WPF.TaskQueue.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<.ctor>b__1() in C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.WPF\TaskQueue.cs:line 59
```

Also the following error,

```
The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual Hard Disks\MobyLinuxVM.vhdx' is not an existing virtual hard disk file.
at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input)
at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.ConstructPipelineAndDoWork(Runspace rs, Boolean performSyncInvoke)
at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.CreateRunspaceIfNeededAndDoWork(Runspace rsToUse, Boolean isSync)
at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection1 input, PSDataCollection1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection1 input, PSDataCollection1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Invoke(IEnumerable input, PSInvocationSettings settings)
at Docker.Core.PowerShell.Output(String script, Boolean verbose) in C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\PowerShell.cs:line 110
at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.TryResizeMobyVhdx(String physicalPath, Int64 newSize) in C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\ContainerEngine\Linux.cs:line 488
at Docker.Backend.BackendServer.b__6_14(Object[] args) in C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\BackendServer.cs:line 56
at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.RunAction(String action, Object[] parameters) in C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeServer.cs:line 180
```

Answer (score 1):

The latest windows update messed up my hyper-v configuration

The issue is solved in the following way.

- Uninstall docker desktop
- Uninstall Container, Hyper-V windows features.
- Delete .Docker file, Hyper-V folder in windows files.
- Re-install container, Hyper-V windows features.
- Install Docker-desktop again.
- Restart PC.

Thats it.

Comment: An update on this, is to start by only disable Container and Hyper-V on the windows features then restart pc. Then re-enable it again, and restart pc

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to remove incorrect IP mapping with Docker host and gateway in Windows host file at `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` and restarted Docker.